# how can I get the path of a context menu selection?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, contextmenu, windows-explorer, windows-explorer-integration

I have a custom entry on the Internet Explorer's context menu. I would like to do something with the selected item, for example, run a program that receives that selection as ARGV[1].

For example, if I right click on a file named `whatever.zip` that is located on my desktop, the following thing should run :
    my_binary path\to\desktop\whatever.zip

Answer (score 2):

You need change YOUR_BINARY and the filetype to do something:

Create a file called RegisterYourBinary.reg with the content:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip]
@="zipfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zipfile\shell\DoSomething]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zipfile\shell\DoSomething\command]
@="YOUR_BINARY \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 2):

add %L as argument from within the explorer context menu when calling your executable.
For example:
myApp.exe %L